# Question on how to define a boolean in processing

Tags: java, boolean

I am very new to coding and have a question regarding the code below. (It's a Java program I'm trying to get to work in processing) I'd like it to grow the circle with the count_up, but when one of the circles reaches the max width to go back again (in a way to loop the action) I was trying to make this happen with `if...else` but I don't know how I should define the if so that it's working.

```
int count_up = 0;
int count_down = 500;

void setup() 
{
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() { 

  if ( count_up < width/2) {
  
fill(170, 172, 204, 150);
  circle(width/2, height/2, count_up);
  count_up += 1;
  
  fill(250, 191, 171, 100);
  circle(width/2, height/2, count_down);
  count_down -= 2;
  }
 else {
    fill(170, 172, 204, 150);
  circle(width/2, height/2, count_up);
  count_up -= 1;
  
  fill(250, 191, 171, 100);
  circle(width/2, height/2, count_down);
  count_down += 2;
  }
}
```

This is what the code is supposed to do but without growing indefinetly:

```
int count_up = 0;
int count_down = 500;

void setup() 
{
  size(500, 500);
}

void draw() { 
  background (233);
fill(170, 172, 204, 150);
  circle(width/2, height/2, count_up);
  count_up += 1;
 
  fill(250, 191, 171, 100);
  circle(width/2, height/2, count_down);
  count_down -= 2;
 
 }
```

Comment: It's not a 'Java script': it is a Java *program,* and [tag:processing] has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

I actually got it with this simple trick, to define else as:

} else {

count_up = 0;
count_down = 500;

}
}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).